# User registration problem in WordPress

Tags: forms, user-registration

I am trying to make a user registration form in my site's side bar. Users are able to register but instead of getting a success message, WordPress usually redirect them to 404 page.

Below is my form:

```
<form id="joinmaillist"   method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="Your name here.." name="name" title="Please enter your name" required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email here.." required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:right"><input class="submitmail" type="submit" value="Join!" name="joinm"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and below is my PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['joinm'])){
    $user_name=$_POST['name'];
    $email =$_POST['email'];


$user_id=  username_exists($user_name);

    if (!$user_id){
        $random_pass = wp_generate_password(12, false);
        $user_id=wp_create_user($user_name, $password, $email);
        header('Location:' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }else{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code in `wp-login.php` (line 481 and following). There you can see how registration works.

The names of your form – `email`, `name` – are probably overwritten by WordPress. Always use prefixed names in forms to avoid collisions, eg.: `ma_email` and `ma_name`.

[Prepare incoming data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation). Do not just write anything someone sends you into your data base. It may be dangerous.

Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! :)

Comment: Thanks I thought wordpress had already prepare all our inputs. So I think i should not worry but now I will be careful