# Dashboard Widget Form

Tags: plugins, php, widgets, dashboard

I created a Dashboard widget to send push notifications to an app, but the way I have it coded, whenever I make changes in the Plugin Editor and press Update File, the code gets ran and I get a blank push notification.
I am sure my problem lies in this part of the plugin code:

```
if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    // process the form here
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this or a better way to do it?

Here is the gist of my plugin code

```
if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
  //do the stuff with the 'message'
}


// Function that outputs the contents of the dashboard widget
function dashboard_widget_function() {
    echo '<form method="post">
    <p>Message: <input type="text" name="message" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>';
}

// Function used in the action hook
function add_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('push_notification', 'Push Notification', 'dashboard_widget_function');
}

// Register the new dashboard widget with the 'wp_dashboard_setup' action
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_dashboard_widgets' );
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? There are _a lot_ of things that use POST method. :)

Comment: I think the problem lies in that I run the code on a 'POST' Request Method and maybe the "Update File" button also has a post action associated with it.

Comment: tried to post my own answer, but can't as I don't have a high enough rep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `if('POST'...)` just alone -in the middle of the plugin code- doesn't seem right. You can hook into `load-$pagenow` and process the form submission there:

```
add_action( 'load-index.php', 'check_posted_data' );
function check_posted_data()
{
    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['my_prefix_message'] ) ) {
        wp_die( "I'm here! {$_POST['my_prefix_message']}" );
    }
}
```

Please note that you're missing [security checks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wp_nonce_field%20is:a) and [proper prefixes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44880) to your data.

And as a side note, I would solve this [with Ajax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wp_ajax_%20is:a).

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo  I will check out those other link that you suggested.  Not quite sure what you mean with your Ajax link, care to elaborate?

Comment: To process the form without page refresh. Click submit, spinning wheel, Ajax does its thing, success message, presto.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @brasofilo - I added the nonce stuff and added prefixes to the fields.  Still don't quite understand nonce but at least it seems to work.